# PrimeNG dropdown does not open inside datatable column

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng-datatable

I have a problem opening the dropdown, which is inside a datatable column.
The dropdown menu doesn't open when clicked.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="rows">
<p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
<p-column field="size" header="Größe"></p-column>
<p-column field="modified" header="Datum"></p-column>
<p-column field="type" header="Anhangstyp">
  <ng-template let-type="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
    <p-dropdown [options]="attachementTypes" [(ngModel)]="type.id" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
                placeholder="Wähle Anhangstyp" optionLabel="bedeutung" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Anybody can help please ?

Comment: Did you get any error in console window?

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285202/primeng-datatable-dropdown-doesnt-work-with-options-via-column